# Help prove the following identity (Jacobian)

Tags: inverse-kinematics, jacobian, linear-algebra

I have encountered the following identity expression. Can please someone elaborate and explain how this equation is manipulated?
[image]

Comment: Is this not just the difference between left and right multiplication of matrices?